# Why is Ruby bundler (w/ whiskey_disk and RVM) complaining that an installed Gem is not >=0?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rake, bundler

This is my error message:

```
Running rake deploy:post_setup...
rake aborted!
You have requested:
  nokogiri >= 0

The bundle currently has nokogiri locked at 1.5.5.
Try running `bundle update nokogiri`
```

Is this message telling me that 1.5.5 somehow does not meet the ">= 0" requirement?  That doesn't sound right.

If I am interpreting this wrong, how should I interpret it?

(Ruby is jruby-1.6.7.2, bundle is 1.1.4.  This rake task is actually run via whiskey_disk, if that's important.)

**== EIGHT MONTHS LATER ==**

I'm finding the same error.  Again, trying to use whiskey_disk, so I suspect this is whiskey_disk-related.

This time, it's with the bcrypt gem.

```
3052 ~/dev/myproj$ bundle exec wd setup --to=grant
Deploying grant@<myserver>.com...
grant@<myserver>.com's password: 
Repository already cloned to [/home/grant/myproj].  Skipping.
Running rake deploy:post_setup...
rake aborted!
You have requested:
  bcrypt-ruby >= 0

The bundle currently has bcrypt-ruby locked at 3.0.1.
Try running `bundle update bcrypt-ruby`
```

Again, what the heck?  I'm requesting something greater than 0, and it's complaining because the bundle has the gem and it's greater than 0!  What's the problem?

The Gemfile contains simply `gem 'bcrypt-ruby'` - no version specified.  Version 3.0.1 should be perfectly acceptable.

I've tried doing `bundle update` and `bundle update bcrypt-ruby` on the target server, but neither changes anything.

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock? And can you post the part of your environment where you Bundler.require or Bundler.setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems came down to the fact that my RVM's Ruby wasn't being used by *any* of the remote commands.  They kept using the distro's non-RVM Ruby.

So, two fixes were needed:

1. Needed to change the RVM path line in my .bashrc:

   `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting`

   need to be changed to prioritize RVM, like this:

   `PATH=$HOME/.rvm/bin:$PATH # Add RVM to PATH for scripting`
2. I needed to load RVM in my post_setup.sh and post_deploy.sh scripts, so that the succeeding rake commands would use my RVM ruby.

   This was accomplished by adding the following to each:

   ```
   # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
   if [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] ; then
     # First try to load from a user install
     source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
   elif [[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] ; then
     # Then try to load from a root install
     source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
   else
     printf "ERROR: An RVM installation was not found.\n"
     exit -1
   fi
   ```

   (The latter was clearly not written by me, given how polished it is.  I lifted it from one of my firm's other projects, where they've clearly dealt with this before.)
3. I also need to run `bundle install` in my post_setup.sh and post_deploy.sh scripts.  This must occur **before** whiskey_disk starts running Rake, so including it in the Rake script itself is not sufficient.

And now I have whiskey_disk deployments working smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not using the correct ruby. Check `which ruby` is being used after you ssh into the machine. If you're using rvm, I would just uninstall the system ruby.

Comment: I set the default rvm to the right one (which I hadn't done), but it didn't change the outcome.  Any way to verify it's using the right one?

Comment: You can try running the whiskey_disk deploy task with debug=true. e.g. rake deploy:now to=your_env debug=true

Comment: Uninstalling the system ruby wouldn't have worked.  It still wouldn't have found the rvm ruby.